# Example of projective, $ F $-regular variety $ X $ and smooth sub-variety $ Y $ such that $ \operatorname{Bl}_{Y}(X) $ is not $ F $-regular?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, frobenius-splitting

A variety $ X $ is $ F $-split if there exists an $ \mathcal{O}_{X} $-linear map $ \phi: F_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}) \to \mathcal{O}_{X} $ such that $ \phi \circ F^{\sharp} = \operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} $.  Such a map $ \phi $ is called a splitting.  A closed sub-scheme $ Y $ of $ X $ is compatibly split if there exists a splitting $ \phi $ such that $ \phi(F_{\ast}(\mathcal{I}_{Y})) \subseteq \mathcal{I}_{Y} $.  Note that $ \mathcal{I}_{Y} \subseteq \phi(F_{\ast}(\mathcal{I}_{Y})) $ already.

If $ X $ is a normal variety, then $ X $ if $ F $-regular if for all effective Weil divisors $ D $ there is an $ e \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \mathcal{O}_{X} \to F^{e}_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}) \to F^{e}_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)) $ splits.

Does anyone know an example of a projective, $ F $-regular variety $ X $ and a smooth sub-variety $ Y $ such that $ \operatorname{Bl}_{Y}(X) $ is not $ F $-regular?

My initial inclination is that one should not exist.  The reason is the following.  The variety $ X $ is $ F $-regular if and only if there is an ample divisor $ D $ such that the section ring $ R(X,D) $ equal to $ \oplus_{m \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} H^{0}(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}(mD)) $ is $ F $-regular.

If $ E $ is the exceptional divisor of $ \operatorname{Bl}_{Y}(X) $, then there exist $ a,b \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ aD-bE $ is ample.  If $ \pi: \operatorname{Bl}_{Y}(X) \to X $ is the natural projection morphism, and we denote $ \operatorname{Bl}_{Y}(X) $ by $ Z $, then $ R(X,D) \cong \left(\oplus_{0 < i <b} \oplus_{m \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} R(Z, a\pi^{\ast}(D)-(mb+i)E)\right) \oplus R(Z, a\pi^{\ast}(D)-bE) $.  If a ring inclusion $ R \subseteq S $ splits as a morphism of $ R $-modules, and if $ S $ is $ F $-regular, then so is $ R $.  As a result $ R(Z, \pi^{\ast}(D)-bE) $ is $ F $-regular.  Therefore, $ \operatorname{Bl}_{Y}(X) $ would be $ F $-regular as well.  This seems too good to be true, so I thought I would ask fellow mathematicians if they knew of a counterexample.

Comment: There are many such examples.  If $X$ is globally $F$-regular, then $-K_X$ is big (see my paper with Karen Smith on globally $F$-regular varieties).  Take $\mathbb{P}^2$ and blow up 9 points.  Then $-K_X$ is not big.  I think this example is in the paper I mentioned above.    I also do not understand your argument, I don't see the split inclusion.

Comment: I made edits to the argument because I really want to understand what the error in my thought process was.   If $ S_{1} \cong S $ and $ R \subseteq S $ is a split inclusion and $ S_{1} $ is $ F $-regular, then is $ R $ still $ F $-regular?  I ask because my mistake may have been in understanding the importance of the term "split inclusion".  In this argument I did not have a split inclusion, but the weaker condition above.   Thank you again @KarlSchwede as you have been valuable in helping me further my understanding of the theory that you, Karen Smith and others have developed.